# Failed to attach debug in python tool visual studio

Tags: python, debugging, ironpython, ptvs, python.net

I have a problem with "attach to process" in python tool in vs.
If I attach to process before the next line:"import clr" , everything is ok and I can debug.
If I attach after this line I failed to debug and get "... No symbols have been loaded..."

I don't know why,
(If I use regular debug, everything is OK)

Thanks, 
Code:
in this case I failed to attach in line 4

```
1. import sys
2. import clr
3. while True:
4.     print "Hello"
```

In this case I succeeded to attach in line 2 (also can continue debug all the code):

```
1. import sys
2. for i in range(1000):
3.     print "Hello"
4. import clr
5. while True:
6.     print "Hello"
```

Comment: Can you provide any example code of things you've tried?